# How to generate a square wave using C#?

Tags: c#, signal-processing

I would like to generate a digital signal, which'll then be used to implement an ASK(Amplitude Shift Keying) Signal.

Let's say the message bits are 10110, data rate : 3.9 Khz & amplitude A.

What would be the best way to generate a Square signal(Digital).

I tried the following code, but the outcome is not a desired one.

```
double[] x = new double[1000];
double[] y = new double[1000];
double freq = 3900.0;

for (int k = 0; k < y.Length; k++)
{
    x[k] = k;
    y[k] = (4 / Math.PI) * (((Math.Sin(((2 * k) - 1) * (2 * Math.PI * freq))) /   ((2 * k) - 1)));
}

// Plot Square Wave
plotSquare(x, y, Msg);
```

Comment: What have you already tried? Stack Overflow is a website for discussing *specific issues* relating to programming.

Comment: I tried using the following code but I couldn't achieve the desired output.

Comment: y[k] = (4 / Math.PI) * (((Math.Sin(((2 * k) - 1) * (2 * Math.PI *  freq))) / ((2 * k) - 1)));

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way I can think of is to set y to be sign of a sine wave, making allowances for when it equals zero. I don't know if C# has the triple-operator, but something like this might work:

```
y[k] = Math.Sin(freq * k)>=0?A:-1*A;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I've tried using your code as well, it's better now, but the output period of the intervals are not the same, & it's different ,I want to generate message specific code.

Comment: The different output periods is almost certainly an [aliasing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliasing) effect as you are using integer values for k.

Comment: is there any ways to remove such aliasing effects..?

Comment: In general, you'll always have aliasing effects when digitising an analogue signal if the sampling frequency is under the [Nyquist frequency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist_frequency) of the signal. Thus, in your example of a frequency of 3900Hz, you'd need to sample at least twice that rate: so k needs to increase by 1/7800 in each iteration (presuming k is measured in seconds).

Comment: Aliasing refers to the sample values, not the time going in.  In that respect since the sample values are `A` or `-A`, aliasing is not occurring here.  The sample period IS integer, and that is not a problem.  Again aliasing is NOT the problem here.

Comment: The sample values are a function of time; which is continuous and being sampled discreetly. As such, if the signal's frequency is higher than the Nyquist limit, there will be aliasing. The fact it's a square wave is irrelevant: what the OP seems to be witnessing is, say, -A when he was expecting A...an alias.

Comment: Also note that I never said the values of k were aliased; just that increasing the resolution of k (i.e., increasing by 1/7800, instead of 1), would mitigate the aliasing problem.

Answer (score 1):

`Math.Sin` is useful for sine wave, but a square wave should be far, far simpler (i.e. signal is 'high' for a period, then 'low' for a period).  If you have a `Math.Sin` anywhere, you are generate a sine wave, not a square wave.  Bearing in mind a square wave can be generated with a condition (is x>y) and a sine wave needs a full mathematical operation, it's far more efficient, too.

Answer (score 1):

C#'s [Iterator Block](http://csharpindepth.com/articles/chapter6/iteratorblockimplementation.aspx) support comes to mind:

```
IEnumerable<Tuple<double, double>> SquareWave(double freq, double lowAmp, double highAmp)
{
    for (var x = 0.0; true; x += 1.0)
    {
        var y = ((int)(x / freq) % 2) == 0 ? lowAmp : highAmp;
        yield return Tuple.Create(x, y);
    }
}
```

use like this:

```
foreach(var t in SquareWave(10, -5, 5).Take(30))
    Console.WriteLine("X: {0:0.0}/Y: {1:0.0}", t.Item1, t.Item2);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot CKoenig, as I'm a newbie to C# your code looks very complex for me to understand, could you please tell me is there any simple way to generate a signal.

Comment: ok - I guess the hard part is the (x/freq)%2 -part. I want the an expression, that changes from 0-1-0 for at freq, 2*freq, ... - by first dividing x by freq and applying (int) I get 0 for [0..freq), 1 for [freq..2*freq), 2 fro [2*freq..3*freq) and so on. Then I take this integer modulo 2 and get the desired 0,1,0,1,... effect. By multiplying this with amp I get an signal that is 0 from [0..freq), amp from [freq..2*freq) and so on. The rest is syntactic sugar in C# to generate a sequence of Tuples (first element is x, second is y)

Comment: if you want -amp / +amp you can multiply just add another line in between saying "y = 2*y-amp", if you want to encode some message in there you can take "(int)(x/freq)" to be the *index* into you message and say "y = messageBits[(int)(x/freq)]*amp" - etc. hope this helps

Comment: Thanks a million for giving me a clear explanation, yes I'll try to implement this code into my project. so far I haven't come across Inumerable & Tuples,so I thought it would be a bit complex. I need to spend some time to learn and rest is pretty clear, Thanks again....!