# Generating a square wave

Tags: javascript, matlab, signal-processing, waveform

It is required that a square wave with a 50% duty cycle is generated by means of JavaScript. Through research performed, I have identified Matlab's `square()` function, which is able to generate a square wave with a 50% duty cycle, based off parameters which are fed to the function. In my case, this is being done as follows:

```
square(2 * pi * frequency * [range of values]);
```

In order to achieve the same results by means of JavaScript, I have attempted to use the Math.sign() function, to convert a sine wave into the square wave equivalent, as follows:

```
Math.sign(Math.sin(2 * Math.PI * frequency * [range of values]));
```

Unless Matlab's `square()` function is used, most online resources seem to suggest this approach for the generation of a square wave with 50% duty cycle.

However, it appears that these two functions do not always produce the same results. For the `Math.sign()` equation, it can be observed that when the frequency value is set to '10' and the range of values is set to [0], `Math.sin(2 * Math.PI * 10 * 0)` results in a value of 0, which can then be handled in three ways: either converted into -1 / 1 / removed from the list of resultant values. Now, converting this value into -1 / 1 would not make it possible to achieve a 50% duty cycle, so these numeric conversions cannot be performed (resultant values look as follows: [0, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1]). Thus, in this case the '0' value should be removed from the list of resultant values.

Now, say the frequency is set to '6.67', like so: `Math.sin(2 * Math.PI * 6.67 * 0)`, the resultant 0 value must be converted into a 1 in order to ensure that a 50% duty cycle is maintained (resultant values look as follows: [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1]). Thus, there is no consistency in the way resultant 0 values should be handled between the different scenarios.

I require a solution which will work across all different scenarios, regardless of what the 'frequency' value might be. Is there a way to implement Matlab's `square()` function in JavaScript, such that the exact same values are produced?

Comment: why not generate it directly instead of transforming a sine wave?

Comment: after all it is simply a series of squares, easy-peasy

Comment: Is there a specific equation to do this? @NikosM.

Comment: there is: output 1 for half the frequency and -1 for the other half

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7091093/how-to-generate-a-square-wave-using-c

Comment: possibly helpful: https://www.ele.uri.edu/courses/ele205/Lab06.pdf

Comment: wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_wave

Comment: example code: http://www.matrixlab-examples.com/periodic-function.html

Comment: So, if my understanding is correct, you're saying that I should simply set half of the wave period to be -1 and the other half to be equal to 1. Is this correct? @NikosM. If so, the only issue I have with this is that I will have wave cycles of different periods at some instances, for the same 'frequency' value. So I don't think I will be able to perform the calculation in this manner.

Comment: Thanks for all these resources, will be going through them as well. @NikosM.

Comment: You can calculate at which point of the period you have to change the sign from 1 to -1 and vice-versa. This is not difficult. But check the links given they include implementations with and without sine waves

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201466/discussion-between-questionnaire-and-nikos-m).